# Running scheduled query in BigQuery with Partitions

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I am new to Big Query

I want to run a scheduled query on the daily event files to create a new daily file with a subset of data.

I have setup the query but don't know how to specify the file name of the new file in the cloud console. Within my query I have the event_date field

In the query settings there are the options for

1. Table Name
2. Destination table partitioning field

I have tried BITable$YYYYMMDD as the table name and Destination table partitioning field as event_date but neither of these are working and I am getting "Invalid date partitioned partition key: YYYYMMDD"

Answer (score 0):

Given query

```
select current_date() event_date, 1 x, 2 y
```

Comment says the event_date is a string, which has to be converted into DATE before it could be used as partitioning column, you may do [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date)

```sql
select PARSE_DATE("%x", "12/25/08") event_date, 1 x, 2 y
```

The configuration should look like:
[image]

Generated table has partitioned column `event_date`
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Yun Zhang.  I have tried this but the event_date in my data is a string. Is there any way of resolving this?

Comment: Updated my answer for this